# Spyder Plot Inline

Tags: python, plot, graphics, anaconda, spyder

Setup: Anaconda 2.0.0 (Win 64), Spyder (2.3.0rc that came with Anaconda)

I configure the graphics:
Tools > Preferences > iPython console > Graphics > Graphics backend > Inline

But no matter what I do the graphics always open in a separate window? Is there a way to force them to be inline in the console?

Comment: Did you restart Spyder?  Or at least get a new IPython session going.  Usually the backend gets set up right at the beginning and changing it is complicated.

Comment: Hi -- I did a reset and it works now!!! (odd since it comes as Inline right from its initial install). Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [Spyder 4.0](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases/tag/v4.0.0), figures now render in the new Plots pane by default, so the answer in the comments is outdated - for the benefit of people viewing this question in the future; figures can now be plotted inline by unchecking the "Mute Inline Plotting" option from the menu in the top-right of the Plots pane, as shown below.

[image]

Comment: I attempted this in spyder 4.2.1 on a Mac and the plots still keep popping up.... however running `%matplotlib inline` fixed the issue for me!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the latest version of spyder, you just change "variable explore" to "plots", which shown above the console.