# Spyder won't plot figures inline

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, ide, spyder

I have somehow messed up my Spyder configuration and the plots are no longer shown inline (in the IPython console). I followed the steps, described here:

[Spyder Plot Inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002076/spyder-plot-inline)

But I don't want to reset my configuration in order to get it work. Is there another way? I tried around a lot but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this was a simple mistake. I didn't actually run the code in the IPython console but in the normal Python console.